# How to preload WKWebviews from the WKWebviews in swift5

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, preload

I have two independent `WKWebViewController`. I load the first `WKWebView` and then another `WKWebView` when the button is pressed.

So I want to load another `WKWebView` in advance. How can I do this?

### Each of the two ViewControllers has WKWebView.

[image: mainstory]

### First WKWebView

```swift
    func openSecondScreen(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let openSecondScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondWebViewController") as! SecondWebViewController
        openSecondScreen.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        openSecondScreen.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        openSecondScreen.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openSecondScreen, animated: true)
    }
```

### Second WKWebView

```swift
    @IBOutlet var secondWKWebView: WKWebView!
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let images = global.getIndicatorImage()
        let animatedImage = UIImage.animatedImage(with: images, duration: 1.0)
        self.indicatorImage.image = animatedImage


        contentController.add(self, name: "SecondWeb")

        config.userContentController = contentController

        secondWKWebView = WKWebView(frame: secondWKWebView.frame, configuration: config)

        secondWKWebView.uiDelegate = self
        secondWKWebView.navigationDelegate = self

        view.addSubview(secondWKWebView)
        view.addSubview(indicator)

        if contentController.userScripts.count > 0 {
            contentController.removeAllUserScripts()
        }
        let  localFilePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: webUrl, withExtension: "html")
        let  myRequest = URLRequest(url: localFilePath)
        secondWKWebView.load(myRequest)
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can make SecondWebViewController to UIView and load  WKWebView on this view and you can show and hide this UIView

Comment: @Lalitkumar Are you saying that we should use two WKWebViews for one view controller? I need animation to move from left to right when I'm showing another WKWebVIew, so it seems impossible.

Comment: yes On view you can animation according your requirement

Comment: @Lalitkumar My screen is moved from left to right as the edited questions screens to be. Is this possible?

Comment: you can take idea this url https://medium.com/@adeelkothiwala/menu-slide-out-with-xcode-swift-945c3b100e29 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ej5laXv2dzQ both url help you can make your view according your requirment

Comment: @Lalitkumar My logic is already geared to two independent controllers. Can't I preload with two controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution. But there's a problem. I can still see the animate image of the indicator. I don't think the search is complete.

### First WKWebView

```swift
    var openSecondScreen : SecondWebViewController!
    var preloadCheck = false
   ...
    func openSecondScreen(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        openSecondScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondWebViewController") as! SecondWebViewController
        openSecondScreen.delegate = self
        openSecondScreen.loadViewIfNeeded()
        openSecondScreen.secondWKWebView.uiDelegate = self
        openSecondScreen.secondWKWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        preloadCheck = true
    }
....
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        if preloadCheck {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(openSecondScreen, animated: true)
            preloadCheck = false
        }
    }
```

### Second WKWebView

```swift
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        indicatorImage.isHidden = true
        indicatorImage.stopAnimating()
    }
```

**So I solved the problem by concealing an indicator image when the screen was shown.**

### Second WKWebView

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        indicatorImage.isHidden = true
        indicatorImage.stopAnimating()
}
```

When you press the button to open the `secondWebview` screen, **indicator images** are displayed on the `firstWebview` screen, **indicator images** disappear when navigation is complete, and the `secondWebview` screen appears `preloaded`.